# Autocomplete in Textmate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textmate, textmatebundles

Sometimes I watch screen casts where someone is using text mate.

I'm a rails developer, so these are rails screen casts.

They'll type something like:

def

for example

and "end" will automatically appear underneath.

I do have the bundle for Rails enabled - why doesn't this happen for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The file you're editing needs the right extension (`.rb` in your case) to make Textmate understand the right bundle to use.

What do you see down at the bottom of your TM window? (After Line# and Column#)?

Is that `"Plain Text"`?

If you see something different from `Ruby` or `Ruby on Rails` click on the little up/down arrows on the right of It to open the dropdown list of bundles and select: `Ruby` or `Ruby on Rails`.

This way, when you hit **TAB** after writing **"`def`"** It will auto-complete the method creation for you.

You can also check Bundles > Bundle editor > Edit snippets... (then choose Ruby)  to see if you have the snippet "def" configured to being fired when you hit TAB (see under Declaration > Methods).

Answer (score 2):

For any late-comers like me, make sure you use the Ruby on Rails bundle for .rb files, and the HTML(Rails) bundle for template files (.erb).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Very helpful for beginners like me.