# Is there any Code Hinting for Textmate? If so, where can I download and How can I install?

Tags: textmate, code-hinting

As the title says, i am looking for code hinting for textmate and was wondering if there is anything out there and if it would work for Ruby on Rails

Thanks

Comment: This kind of thing is *very* hard to do with dynamic languages. And it's the job of a fully-blown IDE, not of a text editor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> TextMate provides autocompletion for
>   common tasks but it doesn't check the
>   system for syntax correctness or
>   anything like that. Ruby is too
>   dynamic for true IDE-style
>   autocompletion without serious work on
>   the IDE-maker's end, but I'm pretty
>   sure JRuby will result in some
>   autocompletion support in the near
>   future.
>
> -- Giles Bowkett

Reference: [Autocomplete (Code Completion) for Ruby in OS X's Textmate or Other](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/125902)

Another link would be : [Autocomplete in Textmate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924383/autocomplete-in-textmate)